# What are the restrictions of a probationary driver's license in New Jersey for a 28-year-old

Tags: traffic, new-jersey

I'm having a hard time understanding what restrictions New Jersey puts on a probationary driver's license for someone who is 28 years old, as most of the explanations online are geared towards teenagers and those under 21 years of age. What are the restrictions associated with a probationary license for someone 28 years old?  Are they allowed to drive by themselves?

Comment: http://www.state.nj.us/mvc/license/initiallicense.htm, see "The Adult" section. It looks like you have to have 3 months of supervised driving (an adult with at least 3 years experience).

Comment: @mkennedy, that's for the permit.  What about the probationary license?